# Javascript custom object from json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key

I am creating charts with highcharts scripts and I created a php script, which I am calling with ajax. The script returns json data, and I need to reformat it in highcharts basic column format.

```json
[{"count":"391","search_date":"2015-11-24","search_area":"lastni-pre"},
{"count":"63","search_date":"2015-11-24","search_area":"letalske"},
{"count":"501","search_date":"2015-11-24","search_area":"pocitnice"},
{"count":"114","search_date":"2015-11-24","search_area":"potovanja"},
{"count":"457","search_date":"2015-11-25","search_area":"lastni-pre"},
{"count":"103","search_date":"2015-11-25","search_area":"letalske"},
{"count":"509","search_date":"2015-11-25","search_area":"pocitnice"},
{"count":"84","search_date":"2015-11-25","search_area":"potovanja"},
{"count":"399","search_date":"2015-11-26","search_area":"lastni-pre"},
{"count":"106","search_date":"2015-11-26","search_area":"letalske"},
{"count":"385","search_date":"2015-11-26","search_area":"pocitnice"},
{"count":"96","search_date":"2015-11-26","search_area":"potovanja"},
{"count":"382","search_date":"2015-11-27","search_area":"lastni-pre"},
{"count":"56","search_date":"2015-11-27","search_area":"letalske"},
{"count":"244","search_date":"2015-11-27","search_area":"pocitnice"},
{"count":"77","search_date":"2015-11-27","search_area":"potovanja"},
{"count":"205","search_date":"2015-11-28","search_area":"lastni-pre"},
{"count":"40","search_date":"2015-11-28","search_area":"letalske"},
{"count":"303","search_date":"2015-11-28","search_area":"pocitnice"},
{"count":"95","search_date":"2015-11-28","search_area":"potovanja"},
{"count":"442","search_date":"2015-11-29","search_area":"lastni-pre"},
{"count":"59","search_date":"2015-11-29","search_area":"letalske"},
{"count":"515","search_date":"2015-11-29","search_area":"pocitnice"},
{"count":"83","search_date":"2015-11-29","search_area":"potovanja"},
{"count":"565","search_date":"2015-11-30","search_area":"lastni-pre"},
{"count":"125","search_date":"2015-11-30","search_area":"letalske"},
{"count":"550","search_date":"2015-11-30","search_area":"pocitnice"},
{"count":"128","search_date":"2015-11-30","search_area":"potovanja"},
{"count":"519","search_date":"2015-12-01","search_area":"lastni-pre"},
{"count":"78","search_date":"2015-12-01","search_area":"letalske"},
{"count":"489","search_date":"2015-12-01","search_area":"pocitnice"},
{"count":"101","search_date":"2015-12-01","search_area":"potovanja"},
{"count":"230","search_date":"2015-12-02","search_area":"lastni-pre"},
{"count":"56","search_date":"2015-12-02","search_area":"letalske"},
{"count":"244","search_date":"2015-12-02","search_area":"pocitnice"},
{"count":"43","search_date":"2015-12-02","search_area":"potovanja"}]
```

How can I create an object in javascript, which would look like this:

```json
[{
    name: 'lastni-pre',
    data: [391, 457, ...]},
{
    name: 'letalske',
    data: [63, 103, ...]},
{
    name: 'pocitnice',
    data: [501, 509, ...]},
{
    name: 'potovanja',
    data: [114, 184, ...]
}]
```

I need this object for highcharts basic column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library to help you out.

Then you can do something like this :

```
_.chain(yourItemArray)
.groupBy('search_area')
.map(function(value, key) {
    return {
        name: key,
        data: _.pluck(value, 'count')
    }
})
.value();
```